# If you have a dictionary of strings, what's the fastest way to search a file and increment the number of times the strings appear?

Tags: java, c#, string, performance, algorithm

Let's say you have a dictionary with 5 strings in it, and you also have multiple files. I want to iterate through those files and see how many times the strings in my dictionary appears in them. How can I do this so it is most efficient?

I would like this to scale as well..so more than 5 strings and more than a few documents. I'm pretty open about what language I'm using. Preferably Java or C#, but once again, I can work in another language.

Comment: May I suggest removing the least relevant tags and describe exactly what you're trying to do in the body of your question and replace it with which language/system you're using, and what you've tried so far? Otherwise, it's way too broad.

Comment: For such a situation, your primary concern should be with how to open and read the files as fast as possible. At least in most typical cases, the time to process the data once you've read it will be nearly lost in the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient is always a trade off between time you want to put into it and the results you want (or need).

One easy approach that is efficient is to use a regular expression. This is probably pretty good with five strings and this will be fairly efficient. If that isn't good enough for you, well... You can certainly find a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Pattern Matching Problem. The best algorithm to solve this kind of problem is Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm. This is a fomous algorithm therefore you will find its description anywhere, but it found on Introduction to Algorithm book.

Comment: The regular expression facilitates to build the patron (the string to search) but i'm not sure that it work better than Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm. Even if regular expression work fine, then it must be use that Algorithm as internal procedure.